# How to mount a Windows folder on AWS Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mount, samba, cifs

We have just upgraded our server from Ubuntu 18.04 to 22.04. We can no longer mount our WinFS machine. All machines are hosted on AWS.

```
~$ sudo mount -a
mount error: cifs filesystem not supported by the system
mount error(19): No such device
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

```
~$ mount.cifs -V
mount.cifs version: 6.14
```

```
~$ modinfo cifs
modinfo: ERROR: Module cifs not found.
```

Apparently CIFS is old and shouldn't be used anymore? How can we mount the Windows folder again? All solutions I've seen say to install `cifs-utils`, but it's already installed. It's just not working.

**/etc/fstab**

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /        ext4   defaults,discard        0 1
//172.31.47.233/data /data cifs credentials=/home/hmr/.smbcredentials,uid=www-data,gid=www-data,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755 0 0
```

Comment: Please always include the line with the options used to mount. 1st suggestion is to add `vers=3.0` to your mount options.

Comment: @Rinzwind I've added the contents of `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: @Rinzwind Adding `vers=3.0` didn't change the error message at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Support had this as a known error for that particular kernel (6.2.0).

The fix was to install an extra package:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-modules-extra-aws
```

Their reference was: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-azure/+bug/2042092